# Python 3 cx-Freeze install

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I tried to install cx_freeze, but when I run `sudo python3 setup.py build` I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I know that I can install it using  synaptic but that installed cx_Freeze into Python 2.6 but I need cx_Freeze for Python 3. I use Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like libffi isn't installed. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```